# Errors upon creation of 2d list of my own types in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, data-kinds

Basically I've created a type with three attributes, lets call it "Foo"

```
type Foo = Foo Att1 Att2 Att3
```

Each attribute is one of 3 values, I declared each attribute with this format:

```
data Att1 = A | B | C
```

Now, after a little guesswork about the difference between when to use "data" or "type" I've tried to make a 2D list of Foo's:

```
type fooList = fooList [[Foo A A A, Foo B A C], [Foo C A B, Foo B B A]]
```

EDIT: I also get the same errors when I assemble this list with

```
data fooList = fooList [[Foo A A A, Foo B A C], [Foo C A B, Foo B B A]]
```

This is causing two main errors upon compilation:

```
Not in scope: type constructor or class ‘A’
A data constructor of that name is in scope; did you mean DataKinds?
```

and

```
Illegal Type ["Copy of foolist"]. Perhaps you intended to use DataKinds
```

Where am I going wrong here? I've more or less tried to follow learnyouahaskell to a tee but no matter how many ways I've tried this, I keep getting similar errors.

Comment: You use **`type`** here? This means you are declaring a type, not a value.

Comment: Okay I see - when I use data I get the same errors though. I will edit my question though - thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all the definition of `Foo` is incorrect. Since it here contains multiple values, and `Foo` is not an already defined type, you need to construct it like:

```
data Foo = Foo Att1 Att2 Att3
```

If you define `type Foo = Foo Att1 Att2 Att3` then you define a *type alias*, but define a type alias to the same type (so recursively) does not make much sense here.

Furthermore `Att2` and `Att3` are probably just `Att1`s:

```
data Foo = Foo Att1 Att1 Att1
```

Furthermore you do *not* need `type` or `data` to declarate a value. You can create a 2d list by specifying it as:

```
fooList = [[Foo A A A, Foo B A C], [Foo C A B, Foo B B A]]
```

So here we declare a variable that stores *values*: a list of lists and each element is a `Foo` item.

Comment: Thank you! I will try your first and third suggestions to see if this fixes it - regarding your second point, the three attributes can hold different values from eachother; sorry if that wasn't clear

Comment: @GabrielVega: but then your `type Foo = ...` is just an illegal statement, probably it already complained about this and GHCi probably ignored it.

Comment: Could you please explain to me why it's an illegal statement? Or perhaps the purpose of Foo isn't clear enough - I want it to be constructed using three attributes, each one is to be one of three unique char's (a different set of 3 for each attribute).

Comment: Also, I'm planning on using my fooList in different functions, so if I wanted to declare it as a type, then give it these values, how would I do so?

Comment: You can define a *type* (note that this is a meta-level higher than value) with the name `FooList` (types start with uppercase) with `type FooList = [[Foo]]` (so `FooList Int Int Int` would then make a 2d list of `Foo`s).

Comment: The reason why this is an illegal statement is because `type Foo = ...` does not define a *new* type, it is an alias. So if you would define `type Foo = Int`, then you can write `Foo` instead of `Int`. But if you write `type Foo = Foo Int`, then you define the type in terms of itself, so it is an alias of an alias of a, the type would be something like `(((...) Int) Int) Int`.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying - I'll try and implement this new information